# numerical radius

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-semidefinite, hermitian-matrices

Suppose $A$ is a $n \times n$ complex matrix and there exists a hermitian matrix X such that

$$\begin{pmatrix}
I + X & A \\
A^* & I-X
\end{pmatrix} \geq 0$$

Prove that for every $y \in \mathbb{C^n}$

$$|y^*Ay| \leq y^*y$$

This is a question from section 6 of the book "Matrix Theory" by Fuzhen Zhang. Here's what I've tried so far:
Since
$$\begin{pmatrix}
I + X & A \\
A^* & I-X
\end{pmatrix} \geq 0$$
we know there exists a contraction $C$ such that

$$A = (I + X)^{\frac{1}{2}}C(I - X)^{\frac{1}{2}}$$

Also X is hermitian and therefore has real eigenvalues. Let $1\geq \lambda_1 \geq \lambda_2 \geq ... \geq \lambda_n \geq -1$ be eigenvalues of $X$. It's known that there exists a unitary matrix $U$ such that

$$ D_1 = U^*(I + X)^{\frac{1}{2}}U = diag(\sqrt{1+\lambda_1}, \sqrt{1+\lambda_2}, ..., \sqrt{1+\lambda_n})$$
and
$$ D_2 = U^*(I - X)^{\frac{1}{2}}U = diag(\sqrt{1-\lambda_1}, \sqrt{1-\lambda_2}, ..., \sqrt{1-\lambda_n})$$
Hence it suffices to show that for every $y \in \mathbb{C^n}$

$$|y^* D_1CD_2y| \leq y^*y$$
But I haven't been able to prove this. Additionally if $A$ is a contraction, the desired inequality holds but I haven't been able to prove that either.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I have edited my post according to your instructions. Is there anything else I should do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For every vector $y$, pick a complex number $\omega$ on the unit circle such that $(y^\ast Ay)\,\omega=-|y^\ast Ay|$. Since the given block matrix is positive semidefinite, we have
$$
\pmatrix{y^\ast &\omega^\ast y^\ast}\pmatrix{I+X&A\\ A^\ast &I-X}\pmatrix{y\\ \omega y}\ge0.
$$
The LHS is equal to $2y^\ast y-2|y^\ast Ay|$. Now we are done.